Getting error from newsapi in express.js, while fetching data
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
require("dotenv").config();
var cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*", 
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const axiosData = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything`, {
      params: {
        q: "bitcoin",
        sources: "bbc-news,the-verge",
        domains: "bbc.co.uk, techcrunch.com",
        from: "2022-11-03",
        to: "2023-12-01",
        language: "en",
        sortBy: "relevancy",
        page: 2,
        apiKey: process.env.API_KEY, // Replace with your actual NewsAPI key
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Successfully fetchec data",
      data: axiosData.data,
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.response?.status || 500).json({
      message: err.response?.data?.message || err.message,
      success: false,
    });
  }
});

const port_num = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.listen(port_num, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port_num}`);
});


I was trying to get json data from newsApi but the place i am getting this issue where my plan is not expired or not have consumed it all.
getting this issue always:
{
"message": "You are trying to request results too far in the past. Your plan permits you to request articles as far back as 2024-11-03, but you have requested 2022-11-03. You may need to upgrade to a paid plan.",
"success": false
}
